# Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation) - Phone Login(Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

What steps can I take to resolve the error "Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation)" when using phone login in my Firebase project?. My Email and password Login works properly, but when i tried with the phone login i get the error Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation). This happens when i enter the phone number and click on the button "send verification"

Here is my code for the login.

```
const LoginForm = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const { signIn, requestOTP } = UserAuth()

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  // ... your existing code here ...

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState('');
  const [confirmationResult, setConfirmationResult] = useState(null);

  // ... your existing code here ...

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const user = await signIn(email, password);
      console.log(user)
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
      setLoading(false);
      // navigate('/search');

    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Wrong email or password..", {
        theme: "colored",
        hideProgressBar: true
      })
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }

  const handlePhoneAuthSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      setLoading(true);

      if (phoneNumber.length >= 10) {
        const confirmResult = await requestOTP(phoneNumber)
        console.log(confirmResult)
        window.confirmationResult = confirmResult
        setConfirmationResult(true)
      }
      else
        console.log('Please enter number greater than 12')

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      toast.error(error.message, {
        theme: "colored",
        hideProgressBar: true
      })
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }

  const verifyOTP = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const confirmResult = window.confirmationResult
    confirmResult.confirm(verificationCode).then((result) => {
      // User signed in successfully.
      const user = result.user;
      if (user) {
        navigate('/search');
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      toast.error(error.message, {
        theme: "colored",
        hideProgressBar: true
      })
    });
  }
```

```
> import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
> import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
> 
> const app = initializeApp ({
> apiKey: xxx,
> authDomain: xxx,
> projectId: xxx,
> storageBucket: xxx,
> messagingSenderId: xxx,
> appId: xxx,
> measurementId: xxx
> });
> 
> 
> export const auth = getAuth(app)
> 
> export default app
```

I've Legit tried anything i could think off.

Comment: This usually occurs when your auth is incorrect, or your function to send the code back to the API isn’t working. Also, I’m assuming you imported all the necessary functions from the ‘firebase/auth’ module?

Comment: Yes - Worth to notice this doesn't work with this initialize. I tried with a new project and it works fine

Comment: Good to hear. Perhaps add what you did as an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: The Problem is still not solve for this project. - It just works on new project.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that you duplicated the code to a new project and it didn't error?

If that's the case then I'd recommend perhaps running `npm i` to see if you're missing a dependency. If that doesn't fix it check all of your Firebase settings against themselves and correct any inconsistencies.

Comment: Sorry my reply was a little misleading. - It meant it works with an entire new firebase project with a initialize from that project.